# Bioconductor packages Not Installing with biocViews specification in Description section of Package

Tags: r, devtools, bioconductor, cran, package-development

### Problem:

I am developing an R package and one of the dependent packages is multtest.
It's only available on Bioconductor as [here](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/multtest.html). I am using **devtools** to build the package. And, when I run **devtools::install()** on R console, I would like **multtest** to **automatically** install as with my other CRAN packages if it is **not** already installed. I do know how to install Bioconductor packages **manually**.

### Researched Solutions:

The following links suggest that I should put

```
biocViews:
```

in the Description file of the package for automatic installation of the Bioconductor packages.

1. `biocViews:` is in the line above `Imports:` (I am not sure where it is placed matters as much?) and the Bioconductor package to be installed is put under `Imports:` as [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/r-package-development-how-does-one-automatically-install-bioconductor-packages)
2. `biocViews:` is in the line above `Imports:` and the Bioconductor package to be installed is put right after like `biocViews: multtest`. This exact answer is at the end of a non-voted thread in response to Vivian by Vivekbhr as [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/178056/)

I have also followed up and checked the description file of the packages which rely on Bioconductor as [here](https://github.com/HannahVMeyer/PhenotypeSimulator/blob/master/DESCRIPTION)

### Attempted Solutions:

I have followed those research solutions by putting multtest along with `biocViews:`, below `biocViews:`, under `Imports:`. All of them came back with package dependency or package not found errors as in the pictures below.

1. [biocViewsinOneLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1v6M.png)
2. [biocViewsinSeparateLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IsPH.png)
3. [biocViewsunderImports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhVSO.png)

Then, I manually re-installed multtest and it works. However, I still would like to have the automatic installation capability as mentioned here under the `Imports` section in Hadley's book as [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html)

Is it possible? Am I misunderstanding something or doing something wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi! Did you maybe solve this issue?

Comment: @John, unfortunately, I haven't gotten back around to this project yet though hoping to get back mid-summer! Are you facing something similar?

Comment: Adding the `biocViews` did the trick for me but didn't use it in the end for other reasons

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your 3rd method, and it could pass the CMD check. Maybe update your devtools?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **multtest** under Imports in DESCRIPTION.

However, as `multtest' is from Bioconductor [link](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/BiocViews.html#___BiologicalQuestion), add to DESCRIPTION

biocViews: Software, BiologicalQuestion

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way (for developers) to install packages with Bioconductor dependencies from GitHub is to use `BiocManager::install("username/pkgRepo", dependencies = TRUE)`. `devtools` does not use the appropriate `repos` argument for Bioconductor packages AFAICT.

As with any package, whether it be in Bioconductor or on CRAN, include `multtest` in the `Imports` field.

Do not use the `biocViews` field unless it is a Bioconductor package that you are developing.

<sup>Marcel 
Bioconductor Core Team</sup>